# Meaning of the tab-index tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I found a piece of code from bootstrap which Im trying to understand. Still, there is one part that I don't fully get.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Flexibilní mřížka</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>content</p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zavřít</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

What does the `tabindex="-1"` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabindex` attribute allows you to set the order of the fields in the order you'd like to access them when pressing the tab key on your keyboard.

Adding a `tabindex` of `-1` simply means "Do not put this field in the tab cycle". Therefore, it will never be highlighted or selected in the tab-pressing cycle. You can still select the field manually (with your cursor), but not in the tab cycle.

In HTML 4, you can **only** add `tabindex` to form elements. However, in HTML5, you can add it to a `div` as well as other elements.

Normally, when a `div` becomes selected in the tabindex, you won't see it. However, by adding some CSS, it's visible.

```css
body         {background: gray}
.panel       {background: white; padding:10px}
.panel:focus {background: red}
```

```html
<div class="panel" tabindex="1">Click on me first, then press tab</div>
<div class="panel" tabindex="3">Third</div>
<div class="panel" tabindex="4">Fourth</div>
<div class="panel" tabindex="-1">This div is excluded</div>
<div class="panel" tabindex="2">Second</div>
```

Comment: But even when I set the tabindex of the modal to "1", It is not focusable with the TAB-key. Why?

Comment: `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">some content</div>` this is from the bootstrap documentation. Why tab-index="-1" is set here, when even with the tab-index="1 or 0" is still not focusable? I don't see the purpose of using it here.. @Wes Foster

Comment: In HTML 4, you can only add `tabindex` to form elements.  However, in HTML5, you can add it to a `div`. So whether it works or not is dependent on your HTML version.

Comment: well I am using HTML 5, but `tabindex` set to "1" still doesn't focus the modal

Comment: It does work, actually. Add a `:focus` css selector to your div and change its background to red. Then, cycle through your tab and eventually it will be selected. I'll provide an example

Answer (score 2):

From MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

> ```
> a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;
> 0 means that the element should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but its relative order is defined by the platform convention;
> a positive value which means should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation; its relative order is defined by the value of the attribute: the sequential follow the increasing number of the tabindex. If several elements share the same tabindex, their relative order follows their relative position in the document).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From the [W3C WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#focus_tabindex).
See section **3.2.1. Using Tabindex to Manage Focus among Widgets**

> Setting a tabindex value of -1 to an element enables the element to receive focus via JavaScript using the element.focus() method. This method is used to enable arrow key navigation to elements. Each element that can be navigated to via arrow keys must have a tabindex of -1 to enable it to receive focus.